# Right/Context Click in IE11 using selenium webdriver is not working properly

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to perform right click on a element on a page to open/select a context menu. When I try to do this, using Action class it performs the click operation but not on the element. It executes `contextClick()` command at some other place on screen instead of element I have passed as a argument to `contextClick()`.

I am running application on Windows 10 with IE11.

Here is the HTML code of page.

```
<ul id="menus" class="list" style="height: 613.734px;">
    <li id="1" class="default">
        <div class="inner-div" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="menu"></span>
            <span class="menu-title">Delete All</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menuBtn" title="Hide"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="default">
        <div class="inner-div" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="menu"></span>
            <span class="menu-title">Delete User</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menuBtn" title="Hide"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="default">
        <div class="inner-div" style="display: inline;">
            <span class="menu"></span>
            <span class="menu-title">Add User</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menuBtn" title="Hide"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the code I am trying.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[.='Add User']");
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(element).perform();
```

I have tried with below InternetOptions as well but no luck.

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieCapabilities = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);    
ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

It should right click on the element like it does in all the other browsers, however; it performs rightClick on different location instead of the element given.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Updated the relevant HTML of element.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I got it working. There was a problem with IE installation during OS update it seemed. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE Installation issue was there during OS update. Seems to be resolved after reimage.